# Programmatically searching and choosing a network provider

Tags: android

I'm currently developping an application that resets your connection when your signal strength is too low.

I'm trying to do this by searching and choosing your network operator (settings-> wireless and networks -> Mobile networks -> Network operators).
 I noticed this way has a few advantages over switching to airplane mode:
 - Wifi and/or bluetooth doesn't get disabled
 - You don't 'loose' your reception and this can still make calls (tested this; you will still lose your data/internet connection, however)

I'm trying to find some way to automate this when your signal drops too low.
 Does anyone know how to do this (preferably without root, but if needed, that's fine as well; Busybox shell commands are fine too)?

Thanks

Comment: Did u find how to do it,because even I am trying a thing little similar in my app,Thank you,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: nope, abandoned it a few years ago. API's have changed a bit in the mean time, so there may be an option for it now (not sure)

Comment: Ya but its bit strange that no one seem to ask about this.Still searching for some answers,as far as i researched there is no public API there to deal with it,there are some apps like choose my network which takes the users to mobile networks settings screen,but its no use i need to automate it,hope i find something soon,fingers crossed.Anyway thank u man for answering.

Comment: You could try and access it in the hidden API's using reflection, but that's not a very good practice. Stuff in the hidden api can be changed/deleted on a whim in every new version.

Comment: ohh thanks for the tip,will try it,hope it wont get deleted soon as i implemented it

Comment: Yeah, I personally wouldn't use the hidden API's, but if you really want certain functions, there's no other possibility. I believe there are also frameworks that let you access them (a lot of them aren't very well maintained, though).